# Savig data into a List of the same Model and Foreach Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

What I want to do:**

Save the `candidate.Description`,`candidate.Title`, `candidate.DateOfDescription`, `candidate.Saving` Into a List inside Candidate Model, after saving the Data using a `Foreach` in  the View(**I've done the ForEach already**).

Candidate.Cs(Model):

```
   public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string ProfileText { get; set; }
    public Byte[] CV { get; set; }
    public string CVNAME { get; set; }
    public List<Profile> ProfileList { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public Boolean Saving { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfDescription { get; set; }
    public List<Candidate> DescriptionList { get; set; }
    public Candidate()
    {
        DescriptionList = new List<Candidate>();
    }
```

My CandidateController:

```
       public IActionResult CandidateHistory(int Id)
    {

        using (var applicationcontext = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            var candidate = applicationcontext.Candidates.AsNoTracking().Include(q => q.DescriptionList).Single(q => q.Id == Id); //Recieving all the data from the Candidate With the ID = Id
            if (candidate == null) //if Candidate isn't found return a error page
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(candidate);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("CandidateHistory")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult CandidateHistoryPost([Bind("Description, Title, DateOfDescription, Saving")]Candidate candidate, int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var applicationContext = new ApplicationContext())
                {
                    var candidates = applicationContext.Candidates.AsNoTracking().Include(q => q.DescriptionList).Single(q => q.Id == Id);    //Getting all the DATA from the Candidate with the Id passed in the Get Method
                    candidates.DescriptionList.Add(new Candidate {
                        Description = candidate.Description,
                        Title = candidate.Title,
                        DateOfDescription = candidate.DateOfDescription,
                        Saving = candidate.Saving }); //Adds to the DescrptionList all the Description Data Needed
                    applicationContext.Candidates.Update(candidates);
                    applicationContext.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("CandidateHistory");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException  ex )
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +"Try again, and if the problem persists " +"see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View();
    }


And Also CandidateHistory View: 

    @model HCCBPOHR.Data.Candidate

   @{
   ViewData["Title"] = "CandidateHistory";
    }

      <h2>Canidate - @Model.Name</h2>

    <label>History</label>
    <hr />

     <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> History Of @Model.Name
  </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    @foreach (var Description in Model.DescriptionList)
    {
        @if (Model.Saving == true)
        {
            <ul class="timeline">
                <li class="timeline">
                    <div class="timeline-badge">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">@Description.Title</h4>
                            <p>
                                <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @Description.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p>@Description.Description</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
        @if (Model.Saving == false)
        {
            <ul class="timeline">
                <li class="timeline-inverted">
                    <div class="timeline-badge">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">Title</h4>
                            <p>
                                <small class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @Description.DateOfDescription.ToShortDateString()</small>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                            <p>@Description.Description</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
        }
  </div>
        </div>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@Description.Saving"> Add History Description</button>
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form asp-action="CandidateHistory">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"> 
        </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"> 
               </label>
                    <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Selects</label>
                    <select asp-for="Saving" class="form-control">
                        <option value="false">Candidate </option>
                        <option value="true">Hitachi</option>s
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DateOfDescription" class="form-group"> 
         </label>
                    <input asp-for="DateOfDescription" class="form-group" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
    </div>
   </div>
    </div>
```

The `Candidate candidate` is the recieving the value of the inputed data in the View( `candidate.Description`,`candidate.Title`, `candidate.DateOfDescription`, `candidate.Saving`) the `var candidates` is recieving the data from the db (`Candidate.Id`,`Candidate.Name`,`Candidate.ProfileText`, `CandidateCv`, etc (everything but the Description/Title/saving/dateofdescription))

**With this code, I only have a problem:**

> It creates and adds to the list all the descriptions but in the end also creates and empty candidate(should not do it).

as you can see this "empty" candidates are saving the Descriptin/History[image]**

The `Candidate candidate` recieves this value [image]
 and the `candidates` recieves this: [image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by empty candidate? Where did it create? Could you share us a screen shot?

Comment: @Edward Sure I will add it to the question

Comment: @Edward each time I add a History for an Candidate it just creates another candidate, and this empty candidates acctually have some data from the History ( candidate DescriptionList)

Comment: Why are you doing **new Candidate** inside the DescriptionList.Add? I think your problem is related do that.

Comment: @artisonus what other way can I do this then? I have tryied a simple DescriptionList.Add but did the same thing, Can you try to answer with a Sample code/example code?